# Utilização de rotas no frontend ou backend

Tags: node.js, react, arquitetura-de-software, route, integração

Em relação ao roteamento, é mais adequado o roteamento ficar no *front* e o mesmo fazer requisições para o servidor através de AJAX, ou o roteamento ficar no *back* e o mesmo renderizar as *views* do *front*?

Comment: O que seria esse roteamento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falsa dicotomia, até porque roteamento em um ou outro existem para rotear o que está naquela camada, o fato de ter usado em uma camada não torna desnecessário usar em outra, claro, desde que vocês esteja usando arquiteturas que exigem roteamento. Ou seja, usar ou não, nada tem a ver com o que está preocupado na pergunta e sim se faz sentido na arquitetura usada naquela camada.

Você pode usar um roteamento em uma delas e não usar em outra simplesmente porque a arquitetura daquela camada foi pensada de uma forma que não precisa de roteamento.

Em geral roteamento é necessário para arquiteturas complexas, e houve um tempo que as pessoas só adotavam soluções complexas para problemas complexos (algumas pessoas ainda o fazem, ainda bem), mas hoje é comum as pessoas adotarem arquiteturas complexas porque está na moda, a pessoa adota sem nem entender porque está fazendo aquilo e que benefício terá com a adoção daquilo.

Eu vejo o pessoal evitando adotar roteamento com o React no *frontend* (ou era assim).